# Javascript ES6 modules not passing along .htaccess basic authentication

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, es6-modules

When I run the following JavasScript, I can successfully log in but not access the modules. How can I pass the authentication to them?

**Sample Code**

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>  
<body>
    <script type="module">
        import * as mymodule from "./js/mymodule.js";
        mymodule.runme();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Opening this with a .htaccess with basic authentication results in `GET 
[...]mymodule.js [HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required 1ms]` on Firefox 54 (dom.moduleScripts.enabled, it works without .htaccess).

**.htaccess**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Internal Area"
AuthUserFile /opt/.../.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems that script with `type="module"` does not fetch the javascript file with the required credentials data to authenticate the user by the server.

Therefore you get `HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required`

To solve this issue, You can add `crossorigin` attribute to the script tag:

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="./js/mymodule.js"></script>
<script type="module">
    import * as mymodule from "./js/mymodule.js";
    mymodule.runme();
</script>
```

This will inform the browser to make "credentialed" request (request which aware of HTTP cookies and HTTP Authentication information).

Comment: For an unknown reason, this actually worked. Why could enabling crossorigin  would solve the 401 when loading a script from the same website/port ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that that the HTML is cached by Firefox and you do not authenticate to the server.

You can try the following:

---

Prevent html file caching. Add to **.htaccess** :

```
<filesMatch "\.(html)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

---

use PHP extension for instead of HTML

---

Comment: Unfortunately, neither the .htaccess change nor renaming `index.html` to `index.php` solved the problem.