# Any way to specify additional [HTTP] headers for ES6 module `import` requests?

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules

I am implementing a use case where for security reasons the Web server serving my application's assets would only send content of one particular [ES6] module to authorized users/clients only, going by the `Authorization` header supplied with the request. In other words any HTTP request for the module body, as originating with some `import "./module-with-sensitive-data.js"` statement (or `import` call) must only effectively succeed if and only if the server successfully authorizes the request by the provided `Authorization` header.

I am not using the ["basic" HTTP authorization scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617), mind you. The authorization "bearer" token is issued by the Web service and the latter is the party tasked with resource access authorization.

Evidently, and to state for brevity what is probably obvious and what makes up my immediate problem, there seems to exist no facility to directly specify any additional headers beyond what the user agent would be supplying implicitly, with requests originating with `import` statements/calls like above.

The general form of this question, for posterity, can be said to be about two overlapping, hypothetical features: first, an ability to specify additional headers for `import` requests, and potentially other kinds of requests where currently no such provision is facilitated (`link` and `script` elements to name a few examples). Second, additional level of support by the user agent for authorization schemes other than "Basic" -- where like with the latter at least an "authorization realm" is defined and within which the user agent will at least supply some `Authorization` headers the application may be given some control of, one way or the other. Anyway, this is generalization, and like I said, for posterity and context.

To list some solutions to my immediate problem, solutions I have so far been considering, which all have non-trivial drawbacks:

1. Use a service worker to intercept HTTP requests and add `Authorization` header when appropriate. This should accomplish desired result, but brings in an entire service worker I now have to manage, with everything the API will demand with using it (activation? message passing?) Raising the bar for user agent feature support, again, to add a header for a module import request (granted, probably all user agents that support modules support service workers anyway).
2. Fetch the actual module resource using `fetch`, which would allow me to supply `Authorization` header, among others, for the request, then create a URL for the response blob with the `URL.createObjectURL` call, and supply that URL to the `import` procedure (or even `import` statement if it supports the kind of module specification URL). A drawback of this approach which I suspect will manifest is that the module won't be able to import other modules using relative paths, which it may want to potentially do (configuration is designed to be developed and maintained), because relative paths for `import` are resolved relative to the path of the module containing these, while the URL here is one of a "blob", with all the implications thereof.
3. Set a cookie, which I assume the user agent will be including with all the requests to the domain (subject to the cookie specification, of course).

Lastly, I could solve this with providing the authorization bearer (token) in the URL used in the `import` statement/call, but that is one thing I definitely want to avoid, regardless, for security reasons.

Is there any idiomatic way, preferably not involving any of the above solutions, to provide the `Authorization` header for when importing a module, or any headers beyond what a particular user agent module loader would be supplying implicitly? And if there isn't, would you consider any of the solutions described above as viable in practice?

To pre-empt the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) issue coming up -- me being unclear about what I am actually trying to do (Y) and instead asking how to specify headers for `import` statement/calls (X): as you may have surmised, the module may contain some amount of sensitive information, so it shouldn't be available without valid authorization. The information does not include passwords or keys, but may include personal information that can be misused for fingerprinting or profiling the service, and so it is a minor requirement from our security team to preferably only have the module available through authorization. The module acts as application's "configurator" and through it being essentially a script I can retain nearly arbitrary flexibility with regard to how and what the module is able to configure.

Comment: Cookie-based session authentication would probably work

Comment: Related question: [Javascript ES6 modules not passing along .htaccess basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44720004/215552)

Comment: @Bergi thank you for suggestion, I forgot to mention I kept that in mind but ultimately want to avoid cookies (for reasons I can cover if someone wishes to know).

Comment: In my opinion a better approach would be to serve two different versions of the file. If a user does not have a valid Authorization file, server the content without the sensitive `import` statement. If the user does have a valid Authorization header, serve the full file.

Comment: I am not sure I understood what you're suggesting, @IanGabes -- even if I would end up serving two different versions of the file, I need to perform authorization before I can commit to serving the "sensitive"/"full" version, on the server side (the bearer token is "opaque" to the client in the sense that the client by design lacks the means to verify the claims the token embeds). How do you propose I perform authorization for a module resource being requested (this is what my question is about)?

Comment: I would use lazy loading with two version of the file as @lanGabes also saying. With lazy loading I can create some kind of strategy to figure out which file to be imported. For example, You can combine, JWT with browser fingerprint and do some network requests to figure out if its coming from the same browser used to authorized and then save fingerprint to the session  If authorized, JS will send a request to the `sensitive.js`. Since we added a session, on server side we can add a middleware to check if session is available for the request and only send back the response if session is there.

Comment: @Dilshan The question is not which files to import dynamically, but to statically import a file that is only available with (custom-header) authentication.

Comment: @Bergi I don't see an other way without using cookies. But since he don't wants to use cookies, with the webpack in my mind, can't we do something like this ? https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import

Comment: @Dilshan Like I said in the question, you can do it with a service worker, loading a module into a blob (obviously won't work with the `import` statement which only allows simple string literals for URL), cookies, or providing authorization in the `import` URL (won't work in practice with the `import` statement, again). I am fishing for some good approach I may have missed, instead. But I have tested _all_ of the methods I have listed, to work. Service worker fixes this really well for the general use case, but for my application is a bit of an overkill, although strangely attractive.

Comment: @amn May I ask why you try to avoid cookies ?

Comment: @amn how are you performing authz/authn on the Authorization header at the moment?

Comment: This is AFAICT an XY problem. There is arguably no such thing as sensitive front-end *code*. There is such a thing as sensitive front-end *data*. What is it about the *code* that requires such security? Why can't you separate out the sensitive *data* and fetch it with the proper token? Why is PII (or whatever) mixed with your *code*?

Comment: @JaredSmith I disagree. What little concealment of intent I am aiming to do (on users behalf, no less) by protecting one particular module content from the public and only allowing someone with the right set of claims, to be served said content, is justified by the mere fact the resource is _theirs_. It's a configuration file, it doesn't matter if I serve it as a module -- the intent is for the user to configure the application using something they own. It's not a password file but it's more bit entropy for potential fingerprinting and is thus protected as part of the authorization realm.

Comment: @IanGabes Our service (which I didn't help design or implement) passes JWTs to clients when they authenticate with credentials, and these tokens encode both authentication information and initial authorization claims. Clients pass these back with requests through `Authorization` the header, as necessary (implying resources for which authorization may be required).

Comment: @Dilshan It's a difficult question to answer, I'll admit. Currently, our application doesn't even use cookies -- it uses Web storage to hold client authorization (JWTs). I'd have to augment the code where I set the cookie from a value in `sessionStorage`. These small changes would invariably trickle through all kinds of service code (e.g. our edge Web server setup), too. I also wouldn't want the cookie sent for the entire website domain, so I'd restrict it with a path to the module. It all just leaves if only slightly bitter taste in my mouth, but it'll work indeed.

Comment: @amn that's *data*, not *code*. This isn't lisp. It's a configuration file, that you have unilaterally decided *has* to be an ES6 module (for no apparent reason) instead of any one of the many data formats (JSON, XML, avro, edn, BERT, sexpers, protobuf, just to name a few) that unlike your static assets can easily be securely served only to authorized users. But no, you've decided apparently that what's important is not your users' security but your own bizarre development ergonomics. I've already voted to close the question, but if you can explain *why* it *has* to be a module, I will retract

Comment: @JaredSmith I will only explain this over chat, because comments are very inadequate for this. I am well familiar with the general form of your argument and have long concluded it holds no sway with me, professionally. I am very willing to explain why to you over chat, and will confront eventualities you appear to imply I am missing: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230438/are-configuration-files-code-or-data

Answer (score 0):

## No

As far as I can see, [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#sec-imports) does not provide for any information to be passed other than the path to the module, and any implicit request data.

### But you could use a proxy

There's nothing to stop you from setting up a proxy on your own webserver that accepts the token as part of the module name, and forwards it on to a secured asset-serving endpoint in the `Authentication` header.

I did a little googling to see if module paths can include query strings, but came up empty. (You can probably perform the experiment easily.) But, even if you can't do this:

```js
let secureAsset = await import(
  `/secure-assets/module-with-sensitive-data.js?token=${token}`
)
```

You could instead put the token in the module's path component:

```js
let secureAsset = await import(
  `/secure-assets/${token}/module-with-sensitive-data.js`
)
```

That sort of thing is easy to parse using something like Express.

### Super-important note

Putting the token in the URL will almost certainly compromise your security design, because it will be visible to all the gateways, and will show up in webserver access logs.

Your best bet is to either use Cookies, or per Jared Smith, use `fetch` to retrieve sensitive data from a dedicated endpoint. You are very definitely cutting against the grain by trying to offload this work onto module-loading machinery. Unless you yourself are a security expert, it is **extremely foolhardy** to stray from tried-and-true security patterns.