# Javascript: Changing script type to "module" fails to fetch authenticated route

Tags: javascript, html, express, es6-modules

I have an express server that serves static HTML/JS files along with a REST API. Some of the routes to the static files requires authenticated request (via Bearer JWT token). I needed to change the type of the script to `module` in one of the HTML files to import another script, however after doing this the browser is not able to load the script anymore as it fails to bypass the authentication middleware.

Example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

*index.js:*

```
import {foo} from "../another-script.js"
window.onLoad(() => foo());
```

The server is able to fetch the index.js (however it fails on line 1 since it is not of type module)

If I change it to:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

It fails to fetch the index.js and instead fetches the "Not Authenticated" HTML page.

What is going on here? Why does changing the type to module mean that it is unable to import a protected route?

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @napubza in [Javascript ES6 modules not passing along .htaccess basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720004/javascript-es6-modules-not-passing-along-htaccess-basic-authentication) adding `crossorigin` to the script tag worked.